# ggplot2: Creating themed title, subtitle with cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have a list of data frames that I use to make a list of `ggplot`s, and then assemble into a grid of plots with `cowplot`. I need to then attach a shared title, subtitle, and caption. I want to do this in a way that these labels will have the same theme elements (size, fontface, etc) as if they were created by `labs` instead of `cowplot::draw_label`.

In my real situation, I have several choropleths that each have their own units and scales, which is why I can't just facet, but instead need to build the plots independent of one another.

Here's a simplified version of the data, and the packages I have loaded:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

dfs <- list(
  adults_no_diploma = structure(list(
    tract = c("09003405100", "09003405200", "09003405300", "09003405401", "09003405402", "09003405500", "09003405600", "09003405700", "09003405800", "09003405900"), 
    value = c(0.08, 0.108, 0.095, 0.099, 0.105, 0.103, 0.161, 0.279, 0.056, 0.055)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), 
  severe_cost_burden = structure(list(
    tract = c("09003405100", "09003405200", "09003405300", "09003405401", "09003405402", "09003405500", "09003405600", "09003405700", "09003405800", "09003405900"), 
    value = c(0.128, 0.147, 0.165, 0.1, 0.151, 0.11, 0.179, 0.184, 0.14, 0.038)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
)
```

I'm working with a custom theme (again, a simplified version):

```r
theme_georgia <- function(...) {
  theme_gray(base_family = "Georgia", ...) + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
}

plots <- dfs %>%
  imap(~{
    ggplot(.x, aes(x = value)) + 
      geom_density() + 
      ggtitle(.y) +
      theme_georgia()
    })

gridded <- plot_grid(plotlist = plots, nrow = 1)
```

Following the [`cowplot` annotations vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_annotations.html), I can make a title with `ggdraw() + draw_label("Socio-economic measures")` and manually set things like font size, but what I'd prefer is to somehow define that label *as* a title; that is, the theme would apply everything in `plot.title` to it, and the same for creating a subtitle and caption.

My current workaround is to make an empty `ggplot` with `labs` for the title and subtitle, do the same for a caption, and stack them vertically with `cowplot::plot_grid`.

```r
title_gg <- ggplot() + 
  labs(title = "Socio-economic measures", subtitle = "By census tract, 2016") + 
  theme_georgia()
plot_grid(title_gg, gridded, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(0.15, 1))
```

[image]

The workaround is okay, but I like the neatness and alignment you get with `draw_label`. I could instead add in these theme elements one by one to mimic a title:

```r
title_theme <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label("Socio-economic measures", 
             fontfamily = theme_georgia()$text$family, 
             fontface = theme_georgia()$plot.title$face, x = 0.05, hjust = 0)
plot_grid(title_theme, gridded, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(0.2, 1))
```

[image]

My question is whether there's any way I might combine these approaches to pull all the relevant theme elements and feed them to `draw_label` quickly, or somehow tell `draw_label` that this thing is a title and should get title theme elements, and this other thing is a subtitle, and so on. I imagine some sort of magic like this:

```r
ggdraw() + 
  draw_label("Socio-economic measures", theme_georgia()$plot.title_elements)
```

or:

```r
ggdraw() + 
  draw_label("Socio-economic measures", type = "title") + theme_georgia()
```

Comment: Great answer but is there a way to get rid of the grey horizontal bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

theme_georgia <- function(...) {
  theme_gray(base_family = "Georgia", ...) + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
}


title_theme <- calc_element("plot.title", theme_georgia())

ggdraw() + 
  draw_label(
    "Socio-economic measures",
    fontfamily = title_theme$family,
    fontface = title_theme$face,
    size = title_theme$size
  )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Yes, this is awesome! I'd never seen `calc_element`. It would be great to be able to pass `title_theme` to `draw_label` in place of `fontfamily`, `fontface`, etc. As the author, do you know if this is something people have use for often? I'll probably end up writing a wrapper function for my own use since I need this fairly often, but if it's useful to others I could share it

Comment: It's what ggplot2 uses internally to do theme calculations. I agree being able to pass a theme element to `draw_label()` would be good. When I wrote the function I didn't know what I was doing. Maybe I'll revise it at some point.

Comment: Hey @Claus Wilke I went ahead and wrote a wrapper around `draw_label`. Let me know if you have any use for it

Comment: I hate when people write stuff using library(), so now you don't know from which package each function comes from.

Answer (score 7):

@Claus Wilke's solution got the job done, but I was inspired to write a wrapper function around `draw_label` to get the styling necessary to mimic a theme element. I'm posting here in case it's of use to anybody else, though this might be a weird use case.

This function takes a theme function or, if `theme` is omitted, gets the current theme from `theme_get`. It also takes the name of a theme element, such as `"plot.title"`, from which it gets the styling with `calc_element`. All the requisite arguments are passed to `cowplot::draw_label`, along with anything else in `...` such as `x` or `hjust`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

draw_label_theme <- function(label, theme = NULL, element = "text", ...) {
  if (is.null(theme)) {
    theme <- ggplot2::theme_get()
  }
  if (!element %in% names(theme)) {
    stop("Element must be a valid ggplot theme element name")
  }

  elements <- ggplot2::calc_element(element, theme)

  cowplot::draw_label(label, 
                      fontfamily = elements$family,
                      fontface = elements$face,
                      colour = elements$color,
                      size = elements$size,
                      ...
  )
}

title <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label_theme("Socio-economic measures", 
                   theme = theme_georgia(), element = "plot.title",
                   x = 0.05, hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
subtitle <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label_theme("By census tract, 2016",
                   theme = theme_georgia(), element = "plot.subtitle",
                   x = 0.05, hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
```

Now the only hard part is lining things up neatly in the `rel_heights`, which I could mess around with more here. There might be positioning information to pull out of the theme and use to set the heights.

```r
plot_grid(title, subtitle, gridded, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(0.1, 0.1, 1))
```

[image]