# How can a title with subtitle be added with annotate_figure?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggpubr

I am using `ggarrange` and `annotate_figure` to display two plots side-by-side. In my actual code, I have different titles on each subplot, but then need a common title and subtitle at the top of the entire plot.

I understand how to add text at the top, but how can I add two lines, each with different fonts (e.g. the top title should be large/bold, and the second line/subtitle should be smaller and regular font)?

Here is how I am producing the title. Is there a way to add a `text_grob` to the `top`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame()
plot1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100)
plot2 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100)

all.plots <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2)
annotate_figure(all.plots,
                top=text_grob("Antibiotic Effectiveness"))
```

Comment: I usually use cowplot for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973713/ggplot2-creating-themed-title-subtitle-with-cowplot

Comment: I'm having trouble following how to use cowplot for this.

Comment: Any further guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use plotmath to create an expression for text_grob. See ?plotmath.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(x=runif(10,0,10), y=runif(10,0,100))
plot1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100)
plot2 <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100)

all.plots <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2)
# construct plotmath expression
title <- expression(atop(bold("Figure 1:"), scriptstyle("This is the caption")))
annotate_figure(all.plots,
                top=text_grob(title))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can add a subtitle by using `annotate_figure` twice to obtain the desired effect. For example:

```
annotate_figure(
        annotate_figure(all.plots,
                top=text_grob("Subtitle"),
        ),
        top=text_grob("Main title")
)
```

This way is also really nice if you are trying to use a variable in your title.

```
subtitle_txt1 = "This is a"
annotate_figure(
        annotate_figure(all.plots,
                top=text_grob(paste(subtitle_txt1, "subtitle")),
        ),
        top=text_grob("Main title")
)
```