# Cowplot plot_grid() : Title in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am trying to include a title in an assembled graph built using `plot_grid()`. I tried both the solution proposed in the `cowplot` reference guide [here](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) by @Claus Wilke, and the workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973713/ggplot2-creating-themed-title-subtitle-with-cowplot) as part of the questions itself (extracting the title from an empty `ggplot` object).

In both cases, I am able to construct a object with the title alone. However, when I try to include it into a one-column graph together with two other objects, something strange happens. If I try to include it on top (e.g. specifying `plot_grid()` parameter `rel_heights(0.1,1,0.5)`, similarly to what the first link I posted above suggests, the output include some void space only. Conversely, If I try to reverse the order of the plots (i.e. including the title below the main plots), the output is exactly as it should be, and the title is plotted below the plots.

Any Idea for why is this happening? my setup is not remarkably different from the examples made in the references I included, except for the orientation of the main graph (which is gridded as a single column rather than in a single row)

**MY CODE**

```
# Building the main plots

# ----------
# Upper plot
# ----------

plot.new() ## clean up device

par(mar = c(2, 4, 2, 4), 
    mfrow=c(1,1))

plot(x = range(dato_reg$date[dato_reg$reg == 'ECA']), y = range(dato_reg$sector_any_food_l[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans']), 
     type ="n", 
     ylab = "Number of Measures",
     #main = "Western Europe and Balcans", sub = "Food", xlab = "",
     #col = "blue", 
     bty = "n",
     xaxs="i",
     yaxs="i",
     xaxt = "n",
     cex.axis = 0.9,
     cex.lab = 0.8,
     cex.main = 0.9,
     fg = 'grey')
lines(x = dato_reg$date[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], y = dato_reg$sector_any_food_l[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], col = "darkgreen")
lines(x = dato_reg$date[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], y = dato_reg$sector_any_food_r[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], col = "maroon")

# Secondary axis
par(new = TRUE, mar = c(2, 4, 2, 4), 
    mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(x = dato_reg$date[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], y = dato_reg$Tot_cov[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], 
     type = "l", 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", # Set null superposition of axis on LHS
     ylab = "", xlab = "", 
     col = "black", lty = 2, lwd = 1.5,
     xaxs="i", yaxs="i", bty = "n", fg = 'grey')

markers <- c(0,400000,800000, 1200000)

axis(side = 4, at = markers, labels=format(markers, scientific=FALSE), fg = 'grey', cex.axis = 0.9, cex.lab = 0.8)
mtext("Total Number of Covid Cases", side = 4, line = 3, srt = -180, cex = 0.8)

legend("topleft", c("# Policies - Lib", "# Policies - Res", "Total Cases"),
       col = c("darkgreen", "maroon", 'black'), 
       lty = c(1, 1, 2),
       bty = "n", 
       cex = 0.7)

up_plot <- recordPlot()

# -----------
# Bottom plot
# -----------

plot.new() ## clean up device

par(mar = c(2, 4, 1, 4))
plot(x = dato_reg$date[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], 
     y = dato_reg$delta_cases_week_sh[dato_reg$sub_reg == 'ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans'], 
     #main = 'Weekly variation of new cases',
     type = 'l',
     col = 'darkgrey',
     cex = 0.5,
     #xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", # Set null superposition of axis on LHS
     ylab = "", xlab = "", 
     lty = 5, lwd = 1.2,
     xaxs="i", yaxs="i", bty = "n",
     cex.axis = 0.9,
     cex.lab = 0.8,
     cex.main = 0.9,
     fg = 'grey')

bot_plot <- recordPlot()

# ------------------------
# Building the title object
# ------------------------

# First method

tit <- ggdraw() + 
        draw_label(
                "Western Europe and Balcans",
                #fontface = 'bold',
                #fontfamily = 'Open Sans',
                x = 0,
                hjust = 0#,
                #vjust = 1
        ) +
    theme_delabj() #+

# Second Method
tit2 <- ggplot() + 
        labs(title = "Western Europe and Balcans") + 
        theme_delabj()
tit2 <- ggpubr::as_ggplot(get_title(tit2))

# Does not work
plot_grid(tit, up_plot, bot_plot,
          ncol = 1,
          rel_heights = c(0.1,1,0.5))

# Works
plot_grid(up_plot, bot_plot, tit
          ncol = 1,
          rel_heights = c(1,0.5,0.1))
```

Any Idea for why is this happening? I tried to build the graph building the column plot before and adding the title in a second step, but with no success. Below, I provide a subsample of the data.

**DATA**

```
dato_reg <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18263, 18264, 18265, 18266, 
18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 18273, 18274, 18275, 
18276, 18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 18281, 18282, 18283, 18284, 
18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292, 18293, 
18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 18300, 18301, 18302, 
18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307, 18308, 18309, 18310, 18311, 
18312, 18313, 18314, 18315, 18316, 18317, 18318, 18319, 18320, 
18321, 18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 18329, 
18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 18337, 18338, 
18339, 18340, 18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 18346, 18347, 
18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 18355, 18356, 
18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18363, 18364, 18365, 
18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 18373, 18374, 
18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 18381, 18382, 18383, 
18384, 18385, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 18392, 
18393, 18394, 18395, 18396, 18397, 18398, 18399, 18400, 18401, 
18402, 18403, 18404, 18405, 18406, 18407, 18408, 18409, 18410, 
18411, 18412, 18413, 18414, 18415, 18416, 18417, 18418, 18419, 
18420, 18421, 18422, 18423, 18424, 18425, 18426, 18427, 18428, 
18429, 18430, 18431, 18432, 18433, 18434, 18435, 18436, 18437, 
18438, 18439, 18440, 18441, 18442, 18443, 18444, 18445, 18446, 
18447, 18448, 18449, 18450, 18451, 18452, 18453, 18454, 18455, 
18456, 18457, 18458), class = "Date", format.stata = "%td"), 
    reg = c("ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", 
    "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA", "ECA"
    ), sub_reg = c("ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", 
    "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans", "ECA: W. Eur. and Balcans"), 
    sector_any_food_l = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), sector_any_food_r = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sector_any_med_l = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), sector_any_med_r = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 
    19, 19, 24, 24, 24, 25, 26, 28, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 34, 35, 
    36, 38, 38, 38, 40, 41, 42, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 40, 41, 
    41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 
    46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 45, 45, 45, 46, 45, 45, 44, 44, 43, 
    43, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 42, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
    40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 43, 38, 
    39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
    40, 41, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 42, 42
    ), Tot_cov = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 4, 8, 9, 9, 14, 18, 20, 
    28, 29, 30, 30, 32, 41, 43, 43, 46, 50, 52, 53, 57, 64, 66, 
    77, 78, 80, 101, 145, 245, 324, 435, 593, 899, 1179, 1526, 
    2267, 2855, 3499, 4528, 5957, 7667, 9682, 12008, 14502, 17207, 
    21948, 25650, 33781, 40850, 48336, 57182, 65965, 78327, 92443, 
    109238, 104109, 119291, 133670, 150189, 166726, 186787, 207880, 
    229033, 247545, 268153, 292001, 317213, 340228, 366347, 391125, 
    408620, 431075, 455340, 480191, 506435, 531235, 553995, 597601, 
    616404, 636598, 660851, 694167, 716686, 735861, 756772, 774963, 
    796650, 814188, 835028, 855914, 872891, 886168, 902710, 921151, 
    934798, 954629, 968834, 981640, 991798, 1002663, 1016059, 
    1038908, 1053239, 1067231, 1079238, 1087868, 1097826, 1111055, 
    1122862, 1135539, 1148532, 1152011, 1160828, 1168828, 1178849, 
    1189528, 1199234, 1215186, 1222710, 1228846, 1235014, 1242656, 
    1251069, 1263659, 1271301, 1280131, 1285518, 1289965, 1006491, 
    1011167, 1015849, 1021596, 1030570, 1034475, 1038257, 1043582, 
    1048289, 1053243, 1058091, 1063284, 1067521, 1068086, 1073092, 
    1077711, 1082519, 1087033, 1090777, 1094066, 1097409, 1101924, 
    1107192, 1111933, 1116564, 1121333, 1124695, 1127855, 1132052, 
    1135751, 1139260, 1143411, 1147672, 1151121, 1153914, 1157815, 
    1163128, 1167502, 1172161, 1177010, 1181115, 1184497, 1189332, 
    1194167), delta_cases_week_sh = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.15, 6.15, 6.15, 6.15, 6.15, 6.15, 
    6.15, 1.02097902097902, 1.02097902097902, 1.02097902097902, 
    1.02097902097902, 1.02097902097902, 1.02097902097902, 1.02097902097902, 
    0.294117647058824, 0.294117647058824, 0.294117647058824, 
    0.294117647058824, 0.294117647058824, 0.294117647058824, 
    0.294117647058824, 2.25133689839572, 2.25133689839572, 2.25133689839572, 
    2.25133689839572, 2.25133689839572, 2.25133689839572, 2.25133689839572, 
    9.35608552631579, 9.35608552631579, 9.35608552631579, 9.35608552631579, 
    9.35608552631579, 9.35608552631579, 9.35608552631579, 4.91439688715953, 
    4.91439688715953, 4.91439688715953, 4.91439688715953, 4.91439688715953, 
    4.91439688715953, 4.91439688715953, 3.61151987110634, 3.61151987110634, 
    3.61151987110634, 3.61151987110634, 3.61151987110634, 3.61151987110634, 
    3.61151987110634, 2.18097278915526, 2.18097278915526, 2.18097278915526, 
    2.18097278915526, 2.18097278915526, 2.18097278915526, 2.18097278915526, 
    1.30624242601752, 1.30624242601752, 1.30624242601752, 1.30624242601752, 
    1.30624242601752, 1.30624242601752, 1.30624242601752, 0.658109956784521, 
    0.658109956784521, 0.658109956784521, 0.658109956784521, 
    0.658109956784521, 0.658109956784521, 0.658109956784521, 
    0.363328034068481, 0.363328034068481, 0.363328034068481, 
    0.363328034068481, 0.363328034068481, 0.363328034068481, 
    0.363328034068481, 0.24245404589266, 0.24245404589266, 0.24245404589266, 
    0.24245404589266, 0.24245404589266, 0.24245404589266, 0.24245404589266, 
    0.133501787648649, 0.133501787648649, 0.133501787648649, 
    0.133501787648649, 0.133501787648649, 0.133501787648649, 
    0.133501787648649, 0.0834565412298084, 0.0834565412298084, 
    0.0834565412298084, 0.0834565412298084, 0.0834565412298084, 
    0.0834565412298084, 0.0834565412298084, 0.0625291317023914, 
    0.0625291317023914, 0.0625291317023914, 0.0625291317023914, 
    0.0625291317023914, 0.0625291317023914, 0.0625291317023914, 
    0.0449483257607112, 0.0449483257607112, 0.0449483257607112, 
    0.0449483257607112, 0.0449483257607112, 0.0449483257607112, 
    0.0449483257607112, 0.0348509652307993, 0.0348509652307993, 
    0.0348509652307993, 0.0348509652307993, 0.0348509652307993, 
    0.0348509652307993, 0.0348509652307993, 0.0290414713215884, 
    0.0290414713215884, 0.0290414713215884, 0.0290414713215884, 
    0.0290414713215884, 0.0290414713215884, 0.0290414713215884, 
    0.0250526276453955, 0.0250526276453955, 0.0250526276453955, 
    0.0250526276453955, 0.0250526276453955, 0.0250526276453955, 
    0.0250526276453955, 0.0240567914961615, 0.0240567914961615, 
    0.0240567914961615, 0.0240567914961615, 0.0240567914961615, 
    0.0240567914961615, 0.0240567914961615, 0.0247184338499397, 
    0.0247184338499397, 0.0247184338499397, 0.0247184338499397, 
    0.0247184338499397, 0.0247184338499397, 0.0247184338499397, 
    0.0240095369396734, 0.0240095369396734, 0.0240095369396734, 
    0.0240095369396734, 0.0240095369396734, 0.0240095369396734, 
    0.0240095369396734, 0.0231936536897942, 0.0231936536897942, 
    0.0231936536897942, 0.0231936536897942, 0.0231936536897942, 
    0.0231936536897942, 0.0231936536897942, 0.0233031474558156, 
    0.0233031474558156, 0.0233031474558156, 0.0233031474558156, 
    0.0233031474558156, 0.0233031474558156, 0.0233031474558156, 
    -0.709567845919194)), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Have you added a nrow=3 in addition to ncol=1?

Comment: Hi @Jonni, thank you for your reply. I tried that too, but with no results.

Comment: It would help if you could simplify your code so it's a minimal example, and also use a built-in dataset rather than your own data. See e.g. here: https://www.tidyverse.org/help/

Comment: Dear @ClausWilke, thank you for your reply. I will do it as soon as possible, since I would like to know why replicating the code from your wilkelab site works, while it does not with mine (also bacause the only relevant changes consist of the class of the objects I want to put in the grid, the margins, and the orientation of the grid - column vs row). As a temporary solution, the workaround proposed in the answer below worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It is adding the title as a label and removing it from the rel_heights position. Note also that the rel_heights equal 1.

```
titnew = "Western Europe and Balcans"

plot_grid(up_plot, bot_plot, ncol = 1, labels = titnew, label_y = 1, rel_heights = c(.65,.35))
```